# SQL query does not work when using two filters

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working on an SQL Query that will be implemented into my website in order to display a table. This particular query will only fill one table cell with the number it counts.

Currently thanks to the final INNER JOIN below, it is only counting rows when the primary key (column1) is found less than 3 times in Table 5. Up till here the query works perfectly.

```
SELECT COUNT (a.column1) AS test
    FROM Table1 a
    INNER JOIN Table2 b ON […]
    INNER JOIN Table3 c ON […]
    INNER JOIN Table4 d ON […]
    INNER JOIN (SELECT column1 FROM Table 5 GROUP BY column1 HAVING COUNT (column1)<3) e ON e.column1=a.column1
    WHERE a.column2 IS NULL
```

The problem is that I also want to count rows that do not appear in Table5 (but exist in Table1). Currently the only way I have gotten this to work is by adding the following code

```
AND a.column1 NOT IN (SELECT f.column1 FROM Table5 f)
```

However, it only works when the final INNER JOIN is not included, I can't get it to work with both constraints. Basically, to summarize, I would like rows to be counted if the primary key (column1) appears less than three times in table5 or if it simply is not in table5.

Thank you.

Comment: Zero is less than 3. Why do you need the 2nd condition?

Comment: @PM77-1 Because `NULL` is not zero?

Comment: @PM77-1 that condition is counting the number of times that primary key (column1) is found in table5. therefore 0 would mean that the primary key was never found (but it cant count something thats not there). this is why I have this problem in the first place.

Comment: @Lamak - `COUNT` skips `NULL`s, so for his logic it shouldn't matter. What am I missing here?

Comment: @PM77-1 I think that you may be somehow confused about what op wants. The `INNER JOIN` to that subquery is filtering every value for `column1` that appears less than 3 times, but the key part there is that the value needs to exist on that table. Now, he wants to also count the values that don't exist on `Table5`. So, yes, zero is less than , but thos values won't appear on that subquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a `LEFT JOIN` and add the `<3` and the not existence condition on the `WHERE`:

```
SELECT COUNT (a.column1) AS test
FROM Table1 a
INNER JOIN Table2 b 
    ON […]
INNER JOIN Table3 c 
    ON […]
INNER JOIN Table4 d 
    ON […]
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT column1 , COUNT(column1) N
            FROM Table5 
            GROUP BY column1) e 
    ON e.column1=a.column1
WHERE a.column2 IS NULL
AND (e.N<3 OR e.column1 IS NULL)
```

Comment: @Andomar haha, strangest reason for that I've got for a +1 :-)